# Why does Cargo create multiple directories for the same registry?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Cargo stores the source code of downloaded crates in `$HOME/.cargo/registry/src` (or the appropriate `$CARGO_HOME` directory). I get that each unique registry I use will create a separate directory, presumably to prevent conflicts.

What I don't understand is why the same repository would create multiple directories:

```
$ ls -ld ~/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-*
drwxr-xr-x   473 shep  staff  16082 Dec 27  2015 ~/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-0a35038f75765ae4
drwxr-xr-x  1187 shep  staff  40358 Feb  8 19:10 ~/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823
drwxr-xr-x   380 shep  staff  12920 Sep 11 12:16 ~/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-88ac128001ac3a9a
```

Presumably the hash that is appended to the end plays some role in this. What causes Cargo to create one of these directories? Will it ever go back to a previous directory and continue using it?

Comment: I think one directory is created for each version of Rust.

Comment: @kennytm if that were the case, I'd expect to have over 15 versions (up to the current stable 1.15, plus beta, nightly and pre-1.0 versions), not just the 3.

Comment: Interesting, the users of `cargo-update` also [report](https://github.com/nabijaczleweli/cargo-update/issues/15) that the newest one sometimes is not the one used by `cargo`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The hash is based on two fields](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/blob/c5679e21ef8c7deabce3911ce04ead338ff063be/src/cargo/core/source.rs#L437-L450): the kind of source (central repository, git reference, local path, etc.) and the source's URL.

Cargo used to delegate to rust-url's implementation of `Hash` for `Url`, which changed over time. Cargo's implementation was last changed in [pull request 2737](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/pull/2737) in order to fix [issue 1710](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/1710); Cargo now hashes the URL string, rather than the `Url` object, in order to produce a more stable hash that doesn't depend on rust-url's behavior.

Also, [Cargo uses the now-deprecated `SipHasher`](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/blob/c5679e21ef8c7deabce3911ce04ead338ff063be/src/cargo/util/hex.rs#L20-L24) as the hash function. Because it's deprecated, it's possible that Cargo might change to another hash function in the future (or `SipHasher` might move to a crate and Cargo will use that, who knows).